# How can I create a dictionary where the key is a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I create a dictionary where the key is a tuple?

`dict={} dict.update({value:{}})`

Comment: Exactly that works, just replace "value" with whatever tuple you want as a key

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what the question is. The code shown makes no sense, and does not appear to relate to the question (there is no tuple anywhere in the code). Aside from that, there is no indication of why there is any difficulty: using a tuple for the key works the same way as using anything else for the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you'd do for any other key

```
tup1 = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
tup2 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
tup3 = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')

dict = {}
dict[tup1] = 'lowercase'
dict[tup2] = 'numbers'
dict[tup3] = 'uppercase'
print(dict)

{('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'): 'lowercase', (1, 2, 3, 4, 5): 'numbers', ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'): 'uppercase'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the variable that you tried, you just define a key and value and use 'update' on the dictionary.

```
dict = {}
key = (1, 2)
value = "hi"
dict.update({key: value})
print(dict)
```